# New 'mainnet' version

Tags: kiln

What does it mean:

[image]

I thought that maybe there was new release of Kiln, but did not. I would be appreciate for any meritorical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notification is to inform the user when a new version of Tezos is available. There is a separate notification for Kiln updates.

Over time, this notification has been refined to be more informative. At first, it monitored https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/tree/mainnet and generically informed the user that an update was available. But for users only running Kiln, this was confusing - while an update *is* available, the notification is not actionable because updating the version of Tezos within Kiln requires a Kiln update.

In the attached screenshot you'll see the updated version of this notification (above) and the version you've seen (below). The updated notification only fires if a *monitored node* can be updated. It doesn't notify if the Kiln Node or Public Nodes are out of date because there is no action the user can take to upgrade those.

We've noticed cases in v0.8.1 of Kiln (the last release as of this writing) where the old version erroneously fired. That should be fixed in future releases.
Note that this notification also monitors the mainnet branch of https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/. That will also need to be upgraded to https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/tree/latest-release to reflect upstream changes.

[image: The new (above) and old (below) versions of the Tezos Update Notification]

Answer (score 1):

The mainnet version is keeping the same ("006-PsCARTHA"). But Tezos dev team released a version of v7.0 to support "multinetwork mode" on 7 May.

References:

- http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/multinetwork.html
- http://tezos.gitlab.io/releases/version-7.html